# hdmi2vga or raspberry problem

Tags: hardware, hdmi

I got a Raspberry Pi 2 and want to see if it's working.

I have a vga monitor and I got an  hdmi 2 vga converter. The converter is working, I tested it with the r7 graphic card.

I am using a working 5v, max1.5A charger for the Raspberry Pi (it is using only 1A). The monitor detects the cable but no signal. Nothing else is connected, only the monitor and the charger.

The hdmi 2 vga converter is a Goobay 51758 model. I have read that an unpowered converter may require too much power for a Raspberry Pi, but I am seeing an official converter: PI-VIEW HDMI to VGA Adapter Cable for Raspberry Pi Computer Board. This product also is in the same store with the Raspberry, and it is stated that it is to be used with the Raspberry, but I am also seeing this:

> Note: It is recommended that Raspberry Pi is powered by an external, mains power supply when Pi-View is connected and in operating.

If I will buy the new converter and using the same charger will make a difference?

edit:
Sorry that I say goobay 51758 but on the package it isn't too much to read but item no:51758 but my product it looks like a Aculine AD-004 the first image on the google with the search "Aculine AD-004". It is same color white but a little shorter like the Aculine, and on the back also includes for audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was not the converter fault, my sd hard was empty, i have inserted the raspbian os and there are no problems

Answer (score 1):

The note about powering the Pi externally is to ensure that enough current is available to power the Pi as well as the official adapter. For instance, powering it from a PC's USB port wouldn't provide enough power to run the Pi, let alone any accessories attached to it. The 1.5A power supply should be enough, but taking into account keyboard, mouse, wifi dongle, etc. I'd recommend using a 2A or even a 2.5A supply.

NOTE - the HDMI-to-VGA adapter carries video only. You will need to provide a method to hear the audio should you desire that.

Comment: i have tried directly in the main with the charger max1.5A(can the Pi take more than 1A?) but still no image

Comment: yes i am not interested on the audio, only the image

Comment: The Pi will not properly power the adapter you currently have. It will power the official converter. As far as current goes, the Pi will only draw what it needs, so if you are using a 2.5A supply but the Pi and accessories need only 1.75A, then only 1.75A will be drawn.

Comment: i think the same but i can't see the technical reason, anyway tomorrow im going to the shop

Comment: My understanding is that the official converter is engineered to work on a lower current draw, whereas the other unpowered converters require a much higher current - more than the Pi can safely deliver. Anyway, good luck! Hope you are able to get it working!

Comment: i have tried with another 5V max2.1A charger in the main but still no image

Comment: The Goobay won't work properly. If you want an unpowered converter, you need to buy the official one. Otherwise, you will need to purchase an "active" converter that includes its own power supply.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, it was not the converter fault, my sd hard was empty, i have inserted the raspbian os and now all is ok